# How to install an app by drag-and-drop onto the Simulator window?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have seen the following feature in the change log for Xcode 8.2

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

- Simulator installs an app by drag-and-drop onto the Simulator window

But I have tried drag-and-drop with .app file built for the Simulator, but nothing happens. Does anyone know how this feature is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 10):

[I wrote a small blog post about this](https://medium.com/@hollanderbart/new-features-in-xcode-8-2-simulator-fc64a4014a5f).

In brief: use an `.app` that is built for iphonesimulator.

Comment: Thanks on good post. That is exactly what I am trying to do. I know that IPA cannot be run in simulator. I am trying to launch .app from derived data but once I drop it to simulator nothing happens. Did you use Sierra or El Capitan? I am still on El Capitan maybe this is the issue as I noticed that 10.2 version on iOS simulator crashes on El Capitan when taking screenshots

Comment: I'm using El Capitain. Try the Debug-iphonesimulator version in DerivedData. This .app version should work.

Comment: Can you briefly summarize the blog post inline? To quote the SO rules: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline"